# Google Play Billing Library Weird Behaviour

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am using the Google Play Billing Library version 3.0.3 for my in-app purchases. However whenever the user tries to pay using Google Pay, it always fails the first time. In console it shows payment pending which eventually fails in 30 mins or so. Anyone else facing this issue?

Comment: In console did you get any error logged after failing?

Comment: No error message , the order remains in a 'Pending State' and eventually moves to 'Canceled'. The billingresponseCode is always 'USER_CANCELED' so the purchase is not going through.